# What does creating and dropping an index to a table in sql server

Tags: sql-server, amazon-web-services, performance, indexing

I have big heap table with 17093139 rows. This table is the most heavily used table in the database. Since this is a heap table, there are only non-clustered indexes in this table. I rebuild/reorganize fragmented indexes on this table regularly. These days we are facing a issue very regularly:

Lot of queries accessing this table would suddenly start taking longer than usual. When I check, I observe that the execution plan for the queries have changed. I create and drop a random non-clustered index and this fixes the issue. What I don't get is what is causing these sudden slowness randomly anytime and what does creating and dropping the index do in the background to the table to fix it which the index rebuild job doesn't do. I need to find what exactly is triggering these slowdowns so that a permanent solution can be found as I can't just just keeping creating and dropping the index to fix this issue every time. Any help here would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You might be better off asking this question on https://dba.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Sounds like parameter sniffing. Dropping and recreating a random index will cause the plan to be recompiled due to schema change. Then when it is recompiled it will likely be for a different set of parameter values than caused the bad plan in the first case

Answer (score 1):

I would start by trying to find out what is changing in the query plan as you say and then try to understand why it's changing.  Could be parallelism, could be that it's selecting an improper queryplan due to the parameters used. You could find the queryplans, and delete them all so that an old one is not used.  If you find that new queryplans are always generated, look into parameter sniffing.  If the indexes are always getting fragmented, why?  If you are using a GUID for the primary key, that could definitely increase the fragmentation in the table.  I always try to use integers for the primary key. Hope some of this helps with your debugging.  Good luck  :)

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are suffering from [Index Fragmentation](https://www.sqlshack.com/gathering-sql-server-indexes-statistics-and-usage-information/) which appears as you insert or update data in your table. This article suggests methods for [Fixing Index Fragmentation](https://www.sqlshack.com/maintaining-sql-server-indexes/).

Hope this helps.